# Old anime in which a mother gains a power and moves in with a rich guy who wants to study or train her

Tags: story-identification, anime

It's about a mother and her child going on a boat and moving to a city, but the kid gets lost. When she's found, the mother has to deal with Child Protective Services for a while, but during that time, she gets a power, I think, and moves in with this rich guy who want to study or train her. She ends up getting into fights with other women who have the same power as her.

It has an older art style.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site? In roughly which year did you watch this? Was it a movie or a series? And what kind of power did the women have?

Comment: Sorry for answering late but it was a series i dont really remember the power she had but it has something to do with her armor